# How to show other users in Github organization?

Tags: github, github-organizations

I created a Github organization, and there are now 3 other members, including me it brings the total up to 4 members. However, when I access the organization outside of my Github account, it shows only myself as a member. Can I show the other members? Looked in the relevant Github docs but couldn't find anything, thanks!

Comment: How are you doing what you call "access the organization outside of my Github account"?

Comment: Just looking at the URL via an incognito window where I'm not logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this.

[Publicizing or hiding organization membership](https://help.github.com/articles/publicizing-or-hiding-organization-membership/)

Hope it helps...

Comment: I can hide/show my own membership, but why is it set to private as default and I can't show the other members?

Answer (score 0):

As per this discussion, it looks like the members have to specifically select to display their membership publicly:

https://github.com/holman/ama/issues/274